# Question about Felix Klein's "Development of Mathematics in the 19th Century"

Tags: number-theory, book-recommendation

[image]
[image]
[image]
The original version of these photos is Felix Klein's "Development of Mathematics in the 19th Century"

**In second photo**
In this book, it says class-field and decompose 2 into $(1+i)$ and $(1-i)$. Is it not possible to decompose it into 3 parts like $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{1+i}$, $\sqrt{1-i}$? If this is not possible, I would appreciate it if you could explain the rules of the class field.

**In third photo**
And it says $2\mu+(1+\sqrt{-5})\nu$. I understood this to be the sum of "the set of numbers divisible by 2"and "the set of numbers divisible by field $K\sqrt{-5}$". i.e. Felix Klein could have written $a+b\sqrt{-5}$ in the book, but I think he wrote $1+\sqrt{-5}$, which is the easiest. If this interpretation is wrong, what is the meaning of $2\mu+(1+\sqrt{-5})\nu$?

Comment: Is this a history question ? Looks like a math question

Comment: I'm sorry, I will ask it at the mathoverflow

Comment: Regarding the first question, the context suggests that $\sqrt2$ is not a member of $K$.  Therefore the field $K(i)$ doesn't contain $\sqrt2$.  The decomposition into three parts which you suggest is then not valid.

Comment: I'm really thanks for your comment, Could you explain second question?

Comment: Certainly not research level as MathOverflow is. You might have more luck asking this on Math Stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your second question:

It is not clear what you mean by "*the set of numbers divisible by the field $K\sqrt{-5}$*".  In any field, every element is divisible by every non-zero element of the field.

The expression $2\mu + ( 1 + \sqrt{-5} )\nu$ denotes any element that can be written in this way, where $\mu$ and $\nu$ are [algebraic integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer) with respect to the field $K(\sqrt{-5})$.  Since not every element of a field is an algebraic integer we would not write $a + b\sqrt{-5}$.

(I am still wading in the shallow waters of algebra, so other readers may have different views of your questions.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, there is an additional question in the above comment about the first question. You mentioned that since $\sqrt{2}$ is not included in $K(i)$. So we can't decompose to $\sqrt{2}$ But if you look at the 12th line at the bottom of the third picture, it seems like $\sqrt{2}$ and $(1+i)$ are included in K, what should I think about this part? I'll really appreciate if you explain about this.

Comment: Klein's later comments on Dedekind's theory notes "*he considers numbers of the form $2\mu + (1+\sqrt{-5})\nu$ where $\mu, \nu$ are algebraic integers of $K(\sqrt{-5})$*. Since $x^2-2 \in K({\sqrt5})[x]$, $\sqrt2$ is an algebraic integer of $K(\sqrt{-5})$ and is therefore of this form.

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the previous comment.  Should read : $x^2 - 2 \in K(\sqrt{-5})[x]$ ...

Comment: I'm really thanks for your help